# short dates with biblatex-iso690

Tags: biblatex, date, isodate

I'm trying to use the `iso-alphabetic` biblatex style from the package `biblatex-iso690`.

The style contains this code (see here https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/blob/065ab3d7e20c4d797d702d21ffad596cef150db9/iso.bbx#L74):

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  date=year,% Use only years
  urldate=iso,% Use ISO8601 Extended Format (yyyy-mm-dd) for URL 'seen' dates
  seconds=true,% ISO8601 format requires 'seconds=true'
}
```

I want to override the date settings with `alldates=long`, but it's not working.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@online{A,
    author={A},
    date={2000-01-01},
    urldate={2020-02-02},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=iso-alphabetic,alldates=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
    \cite{A}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

What do I need to do to change the "2000-01-01" in the output to "01/01/2000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-iso690` uses a trick to be able to print the full date for `@online` when it otherwise only prints the year (that is necessary because `biblatex` doesn't support type-level date options, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/863 and https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/pull/74 for the history in `biblatex-iso690`). In particular the ISO date format is hard-coded in the macro `fulldate` (https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/blob/065ab3d7e20c4d797d702d21ffad596cef150db9/iso.bbx#L504). You can change the date format by redefining that macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=iso-alphabetic,alldates=short]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{fulldate}{%
  \mkdaterangeshort{}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{A,
  author  = {A},
  date    = {2000-01-01},
  urldate = {2020-02-02},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{A}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [A00] A [online]. 01/01/2000 [visited on 02/02/2020].]